# How to calculate Multivariable Limits in general

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta, multivalued-functions

Like an example, can I say that

$\lim_{(x,y)->(0,0)}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$  = 1

I can substitute $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}= z$ and then use the Single Variable calculus result. But is doing this step perfectly justified and can we prove that doing this step is actually correct. I know the Multivaraible Taylor series can be got from a single variable Taylor series in this way (that is using such kinds of substitutions). But is there a proof that such a way of substituting is actually correct.

**Because in the multivariable limit case the function can tend to zero along infinitely possible paths but when you do this substitution the function will only tend to zero through along two paths ( that is from left or from right of origin)**.

Similarly how do I calculate multivariable limits in a general case. To show the limit doesn't exist is easy, just show it doesn't exist or is not equal to along 2 paths.

**But to actually calculate it is very difficult. You have got infinite paths to check**. Is this right or not...

So how do I calculate a multivariable limit in a general case. Is there some epsilon Delta way of calculating the limit or some way of change of coordinates.

And lastly is **L' hospital rule valid in multivariable case**.

Comment: yes you can set $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. And you have that $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ iff $z\to 0$.

Comment: I think that using the wording *But to actually calculate it is very difficult. You have got infinite paths to check.* is misleading in general, and misleading for you in particular. You have to prove that the limit exists or not. As you said, you can look at the limit according to various path. To **prove** that the limit exists, you have to come back to the definition and to use bounds.

Comment: @Surb in this particular example it is okay. But in some other general example, there might be some issues with what you have just said. Because when you are not doing the substitution, then your x and y can tend to 0 along infinite paths, but once you do the substitution, then z will tend to 0 through either the left of origin or right of origin. It's like cutting down a lot of paths. Wouldn't some error generate in doing this. Or isn't there any rigorous proof that such substitutions ( the you and I have done) are actually correct to do...

Comment: @Surb  or maybe could you tell me why according to you doing such a substitution ( whether always) is right...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  can you show me some example where the limit exists and you want to calculate the value of the limit... I want to see how you would calculate the particular value of the limit in a case where it exists..

Comment: When the limit exists, it is usual to compute the limit along lines.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net and how to know if the limit exists ( what did you mean by coming back to the definition and doing bounds..))

Comment: @Surb so it will work always when the above condition holds true... What about L hopital... Is there a version of it in multivariable case too or not..

Comment: @Shashaank: L'hopital only work for $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ function.

Comment: @Shashaank: My previous comment is wrong. It should be $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(u(x,y))=f(t)\iff\lim_{u\to 0}f(u)=f(t)$ whenever $u=u(x,y)\to t\in\mathbb R$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.

Comment: @Surb  okay, yeah. I was trying to ask that whether after you have done these kinds of substitutions and have reduced the problem to just one variable, can you use L hopital on that 1 variable then. Like in the example above after substituting z can you apply L hopital on z then....

Comment: @Surb yeah I was thinking about that. Thanks.. And can we apply L hopital on u then like I just asked before ( for z) in an arbitrary case

Comment: @Shashaank: As I said before, l'hopital work for function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ only.

Comment: @Surb yes I understand that. But when we do the substitution $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$=z, then it just becomes a function of 1 variable $R ->R$, so can't we apply L hopital on z now....

Comment: yes of course @Shashaank

Comment: @Surb soryy, but  but do you mean yes of course we can or yes of course we cant

Comment: @Shashaank: yes we can.